# How to encrypt/decrypt a folder in SD card using Phonegap for Android?

Tags: android, video, encryption, cordova

I have a phonegap app where it downloads videos from an online source and stores it in a folder called **"MyVideos"** in the SD Card or internal phone/tablet memory.

I don't want the downloaded videos to be accessed directly without going through my app.
Also, I don't want to allow the built-in video player to scan and play it.

How do I do this? Is folder encryption really the solution? Any other ways?

Comment: use . before create folder it will hide the folder like .MyVideos

Comment: @AmitPrajapati using .(dot) hides the folder but the videos are still in the list at Android gallery(built-in media player)

Comment: I know this is almost after 3 years, but is there a solution for this?